# Django mongoengine not connect to remote server, always connect to localhost

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

In django app, I try to set:

```
connect('db', host='user:pass@ec2-23-20-248-142.compute-1.amazonaws.com:47468')
```

but it always return:

> MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

Comment: I tried, but it always return MongoClient('localhost', 27017) no matter what I set

Comment: another information is if I run this in Python console then it works, but it does not work Django shell

Comment: Any solution you found for this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried 'URI style connections' like this one below?

```
_MONGODB_USER = MONGO_USER
_MONGODB_PASSWD = MONGO_PASSWD
_MONGODB_HOST = 'ec2-23-20-248-142.compute-1.amazonaws.com:47468'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'db'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' % (_MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)
 mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST)
```